# GetProcAddress не видит функцию

Tags: qt, dll, fann

Пытаюсь динамически загрузить библиотеку [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/download/). Цель изначально состояла в том, чтобы подключить её к Qt, но официальный враппер, видимо, предназначен для подключения исключительно компилятором VS.

Написал свой простейший врапер, в котором содержится большинство функций, и их загрузку посредством `GetProcAddress`. Итого, из 83 функций он загружает только 2, а на остальных выдает ошибку, что данной функции нет в файле.

У всех проставлено `__declspec(dllexport)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу сказать, по какой причине Ваш собственный враппер работает некорректно, однако, как сама библиотека, так и её официальный C++-враппер вроде бы без проблем собираются компилятором MinGW 4.9.1 из состава Qt 5.4.1 (наверняка и с другими версиями MinGW будет собираться).

По [ссылке](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mthgba25beevghf/AACRHkhmfDSRVoYNjW1OTMo9a?dl=0) пример сборки.

**Обновление**

Я собирал под win7 x86 (версии Qt и MinGW уже обозначены в ответе), поэтому, если Вы использовали мои файлы, то, возможно, имеется некая несовместимость с Вашей средой. Не могу предполагать, в чём конкретно эта несовместимость может заключаться, т.к. деталей Вы до сих пор не уточнили. А вообще я рекомендую тогда собрать flann самостоятельно и подключать именно свою сборку к проекту. Если же будут проблемы, то соответственно публиковать здесь вопросы с указанием конкретных ошибок, которые будут возникать. Гадание редко приводит к профиту.

**Обновление 2**

Ну как раз ошибки говорящие. Попробовал у себя собрать. Также ругнулось. Посмотрел заголовочный "fann_cpp.h". Проблема в том, что он не подключает "fann.h". Может разрабы это забыли сделать или ещё по какой причине, но факт. Я просто добавил подключение "fann.h" перед "fann_cpp.h" и ошибок не стало.

Вот так корректно можно подключить fann в Qt-проект:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/include

    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../FANN-2.2.0/src/ \
        -lfann -ldoublefann -lfixedfann -lfloatfann
}
```

**$$PWD** означает путь к папке с исходниками текущего проекта. Слэш - прямой, а не обратный, как это принято обычно в виндовс. Обе папки с fann должны лежать на одном уровне с папкой исходников проекта (ну либо нужно поправить путь на собственный).

Comment: Скомпилированная библиотека очень кстати
Но вот как подключить её?
Добавил в *.pro файл 2 строки:

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\Envy\Downloads\FANN\fann-2.2.0-source\src\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\Users\Envy\Downloads\FANN\fann-2.2.0\src" -lfann -ldoublefann -lfixedfann -lfloatfann

+ #include <fann_cpp.h> в код

Но компилировать по прежнему отказывается, много ошибок

Comment: Моя конфигурация отличается, но врядле это критично:
Win7 x64, Qt 5.4.0
Если честно, я незнаю как собрать эту библиотеку в qt, плохо знаком с mingw b и cmake. Ошибки же тоже врядли много вам скажут: http://i.imgur.com/s1pIe6G.png

Comment: Обновил ответ дополнением.

Comment: Пускай меня забанят, но я все же скажу
Вы - волшебник

Comment: Ничего волшебного. Пожалуйста.